# pyshark - How can I print destination ip during livecapture?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wireshark, pyshark

I am new to pyshark.
I am trying to print in the terminal the "destination ip" from the handshakes packets during livecapture with udp filter. (python3)

I couldn't find something useful in hours so this is my last option.
Here is my attempt.

```
import pyshark

file = "C:/Users/S0B0/Desktop/capture/output6" +  ".cap"
output = open(file, "w")
time = 86399

capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface="Ethernet",bpf_filter="udp",output_file=file,only_summaries=True)
capture.set_debug()
capture.sniff(timeout=time)

for p in capture:
    if hasattr(p, 'udp'):
        print(p.udp.srcport + ' -- ' + p.udp.dstport)

output.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface="en0")
capture.set_debug()
for packet in capture.sniff_continuously():
if hasattr(packet, 'udp'):
    protocol = packet.transport_layer
    source_address = packet.ip.src
    source_port = packet[packet.transport_layer].srcport
    destination_address = packet.ip.dst
    destination_port = packet[packet.transport_layer].dstport
    print(f'{protocol}  {source_address}:{source_port} --> {destination_address}:{destination_port}')
```

I have a document and code examples on GitHub named [pyshark packet analysis](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/pyshark_packet_analysis) that you might find useful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! it helped me,I managed to do what I wanted using your examples <3

Comment: @S0B0 you're welcome.  I'm glad that I could help.  Check out that document that I wrote and the code examples for pyshark.